# Find files matching a regex pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

How do I find text files (.txt) that starts with the letter "M" in the current directory in bash?

I have tried `find -E . -type f -regex '^M[^/]*\.txt$'` but it doesn't work. 
Using `\./'^M[^/]*\.txt$'` (adding `\./` in front) doesn't work either.

Comment: Isn't _regex_ a bit over an overkill? `-name 'M*.txt'` would do just fine.

Comment: *Files that starts with the letter "M" in the current directory*!! Use simply `for file in M*;do`, `ls M*`, or so... Only: `M*` as args.

Comment: Sorry: ***text files (.txt) that starts with the letter "M" in the current directory***: `M*.txt` !!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

```
find . -type d ! -name . -prune -o -type f -name 'M*.txt' -print
```

Comment: Btw: [you don't need `find` too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878432/find-files-matching-a-regex-pattern?noredirect=1#comment137296449_77878432)

Answer (score 0):

To

> find text files (.txt) that starts with the letter "M" in the current
> directory

all you need is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'M*.txt'
```

but if you wanted to use a regex for some reason:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './M.*\.txt'
```

You don't need the `^` or `$` anchors that you have in your regexps as the regexp by definition has to match the full path but it wouldn't hurt to leave them in `-regex '^./M.*\.txt$'`, and you can escape the leading `.` or not since only a literal `.` can be present before the `/`, `-regex '^\./M.*\.txt$'`.

Your regexps were failing because:

- `'^M[^/]*\.txt$'` is missing the directory part before `M`
- `\./'^M[^/]*\.txt$'` has a start of string anchor `^` in the middle of the regexp where it can never match.

If you just want a list of files that start with M and end in `.txt` and are sure you won't have any directories with names that match that pattern then all you need is:

```
printf '%s\n' M*.txt
```

if they can't have newlines in their name or:

```
printf '%s\0' M*.txt
```

if they can.

Comment: Why not [simply `M*.txt` as args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878432/find-files-matching-a-regex-pattern?noredirect=1#comment137296449_77878432)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub that IS what I used for the glob version but for the regexp version, which I assume is what you're really commenting on, the regexp has to match the whole path to the file, not just the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Given (in the current directory):

```
$ ls -1
l0.txt
l1.txt
l2.txt
l3.txt
m0.txt
m1.txt
m2.txt
m3.txt
n0.txt
n1.txt
n2.txt
n3.txt
```

Just use a glob:

```
$ printf '%s\n' m*.txt
m0.txt
m1.txt
m2.txt
m3.txt
```

If you want to skip links and directories (which would otherwise be picked up by the glob) you can filter those out:

```
for fn in m*.txt; do
    [[ -d $fn ]] && continue
    echo "$fn"
done
```